# Oracle JPX File import abort

Tags: oracle

I run the following command to import my .jpx file (which I've uploaded to the server):

```
C:\jdeveloper\jdevbin\oaext\bin\jpximport C:\jdeveloper\jdevhome\jdev\myclasses\ORAR12DEV.jpx -username username -password password -dbconnection "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mydb.mycompany.com)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(DEV)))"
```

The problem is the import just quits with an error that says "Aborted". Nothing else. Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

(The jpx file was generated by jDeveloper, so I **think** it's good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword `SID` is missing in the `TNS` entry `...(CONNECT_DATA=(DEV))...`-

Corrected command-

```
C:\jdeveloper\jdevbin\oaext\bin\jpximport C:\jdeveloper\jdevhome\jdev\myclasses\ORAR12DEV.jpx -username username -password password -dbconnection "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mydb.mycompany.com)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DEV)))"
```

Comment: Oops, I copied and pasted this from another thread...I've even tried with the SID identifier, but it still chokes, only saying "Aborted" when throwing the error...